# Is there any other way instead of using too many if else statements for checking the request contains both email and password in login page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

```
const User = require("./db/User");
const app = express();

app.post("/login", async (req, resp) => {
  if (req.body.password && req.body.email)
  {
    let user = await User.findOne(req.body).select("-password");
    if (user)
    {
       resp.send(user);
    }
    else
    {
       resp.send({ result: "no user found" });
    }
  }
  else
  {
     resp.send({ result: "password or email is missing" });
  }
});
```

I used if else to check whether the request coming from login page contains both email and password. But is there any other way to do this without using if else or comparatively less number of times.

Answer (score 1):

```
const User = require("./db/User");
const app = express();

app.post("/login", async (req, resp) => {
    let status = { result: "password or email is missing" };

    if (req.body.password && req.body.email)
    {
        let user = await User.findOne(req.body).select("-password");
        status = { result: "no user found" };
        if (user)
        {
            status = user;
        }
    }
    resp.send(status);
});
```